# How to know current max job_id value in Oracle as a non-dba user?

Tags: oracle11g, jobs

I have connected to oracle11g as a non-dba user. I need to create a new Oracle Job. In my job creation query I need to set a unique 'job_id' that do not conflict with existing dbms_jobs. My plan is to select job_ids from entire dbms_jobs so that from the result set i can decide my job_id is existing or not. 
But as a non dba user i couldn't query dbms_jobs (from sys.job$).
What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jobs are created by a user, so query [`USER_JOBS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_5332.htm#REFRN26105). This has all the jobs for this user.

Equally, as a DBA user you should not be querying `JOB$`, use [`DBA_JOBS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_4100.htm).

In 11g, `DBMS_JOB` is only provided [*"for backwards compatability"*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/appendix_a001.htm#BGBFBIHF). There's now the much more powerful [`DBMS_SCHEDULER`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72235) instead.

However, the premise of your question appears to be flawed. You've written:

> In my job creation query I need to set a unique 'job_id' that do not
>   conflict with existing dbms_jobs. My plan is to select job_ids from
>   entire dbms_jobs so that from the result set i can decide my job_id is
>   existing or not

The job ID in [`DMBS_JOB.SUBMIT()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_job.htm#i1000807) is an *OUT* parameter. You do not assign this, the package does if for you.

```
declare

   l_job_id number;

begin

   dbms_job.submit( l_job_id, what => ... );

end;
```